# use the same c:foreach in two jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, tiles

i have 2 jsp (body,comment) , in body jsp i write code of a publication , in comment 
i write the comment of publication so i start a c:foreach in body and i want to send 
P.publicationId to comment JSp  .
i want to know how i can do that thanks

```
<c:foreach items="publication"  var="P"> 
<c:set var="tetst" value="${p.pucationId}" scope="request" />
        <input id="pubID_${loop.index}" type="hidden" value="${p.publicationId}">

    <c:set var="imgvid" value="IMAGE_VIDEO"/>
    <c:set var="statut" value="STATUT"/>
</c:foreach>
```

I use `<c:set var="t" value="${p.publicationId}" scope="session">`

to return the publicationid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is :

jsp1

```
<c:set var="test" value="${p}" scope="request" />
```

JSP2(to get var )

```
<c:set var="p"  value="${requestScope.test}"/>
```